# Is it bad if Guided Access is always running?

Tags: ipad, memory, guided-access

Since Guided Access restricts only one app to be opened, would it prevent other background processes like app updating, memory cleaning, data fetching and cause apps freezing? My old iPad 2 sometimes lags, and I'm not sure it's because it's designed as is, or because Guided Access is not exited regularly. It's also rarely restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I have guided access running all the time, however i am not experiencing any slow-downs (using an iPad Pro).
I doubt guided access is different than any other app, so the background tasks should execute.